# How to simulate the Enter button to replicate the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a weather application with a textarea, if you click "submit" you will see the weather results. Now, I want to make it so you can click enter to see the data. this is some code:

```
    <section class="inputs">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter any city..." id="cityinput">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add">
        <button placeholder="submit" id="add"></button>
    </section>
```

This is some javascript code:

```
   btn.addEventListener('click', function(){

//This is the api link from where all the information will be collected

        fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputval.value+'&appid='+apik)
            .then(res => res.json())

            //.then(data => console.log(data))

            .then(data => {

//Now you need to collect the necessary information with the API link. Now I will collect that information and store it in different constants.

                var nameval = data['name']
                var tempature = data['hourly']['pop']
//Now with the help of innerHTML you have to make arrangements to display all the information in the webpage.
                city.innerHTML=`Weather of <span>${nameval}<span>`
                temp.innerHTML = ` <span>${ tempature} </span>`


            })
```

Comment: check the submit event

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a listener to your textarea, if the user press `enter` then you execute your call (here simulated by an alert) and you prevent the default in order to don't go in a new line. In any other case, just don't take any action

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textArea.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    window.alert('Sending data...');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type and press enter"></textarea>
```

You can just put the `submit` code in a function, and call the function in both the cases:

```
function submitAction() {
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputval.value+'&appid='+apik)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      const nameval = data['name']
      const tempature = data['hourly']['pop']
      city.innerHTML=`Weather of <span>${nameval}<span>`
      temp.innerHTML = ` <span>${ tempature} </span>`
   });
}
```

Then:

```
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    submitAction();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

And:

```
 btn.addEventListener('click', () => submitAction());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a HTML form and use the form [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event):

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter any city..." id="cityinput" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Inside the event listener you can then read the value from the input once the `submit` event is triggered. Alternatively you could go looking for the input value inside the `event` object.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const inputValue = document.querySelector('input').value;
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue+'&appid='+apik)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                var nameval = data['name']
                var tempature = data['hourly']['pop']
                city.innerHTML=`Weather of <span>${nameval}<span>`
                temp.innerHTML = ` <span>${ tempature} </span>`
            })
});
```

Comment: adding an input inside a form is enough to make a submit, you dont even need a button, just add the function to the form <form onsubmit="yourfunc()"> and add e.preventDefault() to stop refreshing the page in function yourfunc(e) { e.preventDefault() ...then your rest of the code here }

Answer (score 0):

You need to create listener for keydown event and check if clicked key is enter:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector(".some-class");

textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.key === "Enter") {
        // your code
    }
});
```

```
<textarea class="some-class"></textarea>
```

Comment: Maybe attaching the listener to the whole document is a bit exaggerated, but yes that's the way

Comment: @CristianTraìna You have to do that to capture events globally.

Comment: This is not what OP asked. In this case, also pressing the enter button while the cursor is not in the textarea will trigger the API call. Just imagine if the weather application had a chat, you'd get a refresh every time you go in a new line :P

Comment: @CristianTraìna Oh, I didn't think about it. The answer should be good now.